# Why find() method doesn't show the recent data from mongoDb database in Express.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When the `app.post('/form-submit', funtion(req, res))` method is called then i am expecting it to first save the data using `save()`, which it did fine but then i call `find()` method which shows all the data from mongoDB database except the current data that is recently added by `save()` method.

**I want that `find()` method show the current data as well**. But `show()` method only shows previous data not recent one.
And i thing maybe it is Asynchronous problem

```
//For Put request in index.js
app.post('/form-submit', function(req, res) {

    //To add the current data into database

    connect.then((db) => {
        var newTask = taskSchema({
            Task: req.body.Task
        });
        newTask.save();

    });


    //To show the data into page 'showTask.ejs
    taskSchema.find({}, function(err, val) {
        console.log(res.length);
        res.render('showTask.ejs', { todoTask: val });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save is async

it can either return a promise or take a callback (err) => {}

so you fetch information at the time it didn't manage to save yet

```
app.post('/form-submit', function(req, res) {

    //To add the current data into database

    connect.then((db) => {
        var newTask = taskSchema({
            Task: req.body.Task
        });
        return newTask.save();
    }).then(() => {
        //To show the data into page 'showTask.ejs
        taskSchema.find({}, function(err, val) {
            console.log(res.length);
            res.render('showTask.ejs', { todoTask: val });
        });
    });

});
```

or:

```
app.post('/form-submit', async function(req, res) {

    //To add the current data into database

    const db = await connect;
    var newTask = taskSchema({
        Task: req.body.Task
    });
    await newTask.save();

    //To show the data into page 'showTask.ejs
    taskSchema.find({}, function(err, val) {
        console.log(res.length);
        res.render('showTask.ejs', { todoTask: val });
    });
});
```

Comment: But when i try to place "await" as prefix of save() then it give me error   SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: add async: app.post('/form-submit', async function(req, res) {. or use .then: return newTask.save(); }).then(saved => { taskSchema.find ...

Comment: added example to my answer